# how to enter text and then convert It to other values via java script

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, concatenation, var

I made a script that converts letters into numbers using "var". What is the best way to make a html page to input the text and then translate it to numbers using the script bellow.

```js
var a='1*'
var b="2*"
var c="3*"
var d="4*"
var e="5*"
var f="6*"
var g="7*"
var h="8*"
var i="9*"
var j="10*"
...
var output= [a+b].join('');
```

Comment: `output` is just "1*2*" I don't see how this is converting anything. And `[a+b].join('');` does exactly the same as `a+b`.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

You need a function that translate the letters to numbers then you can call it from an **input**. The result of translation can be displayed in a **span** for example.

```js
function translateLetterToNumber(event) {
  const value = event.target.value;

  let translatedText = value.charCodeAt(0) - 96;

  if (value.length > 1) {
    const splittedValue = value.split('');
    const translatedLetters = splittedValue.map(letter => letter.charCodeAt(0) - 96);
    translatedText = translatedLetters.join('');
  }

  document.getElementById('result').textContent = translatedText;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" onkeyup="translateLetterToNumber(event)" />
<span id="result"></span>
```

Comment: adding a  dictionary as an array for every single letter is way too complicated and long. Check my answer on how to do it the short way. Then I would recommend using `textContent` instead of `inner HTML`. Getting a text from input and then using `innerHTML` is the easiest way for an XSS Attack injection.

Comment: Yes, you have reason. I edited it, then the only difference with your answer is the map function for translate a word.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the letter you like and use `charCodeAt(letter)` to get the Unicode number for that letter. In Unicode for `a` is `97`. So if `a = 1, b = 2` you have to subtract it by `96`:

```js
var letter = document.querySelector('input');

letter.addEventListener('change', function() {
  let number = letter.value.charCodeAt(0) - 96;
  console.log(`${letter.value} => ${number}`);
})
```

```html
<input type="text" maxLenght="1"><label>type a single letter</label>
```